# App Crash (key: $in) Provisional Profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, provisioning-profile

This is what is in the debug area when my app crashes

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: $in)'
```

I have no idea what it means but it does not look good and I cannot find the break point of where it goes.

```
_theUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    if (!_theUser || _theUser[@"Completed"] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginFromHome" sender:self];
        return;
    }
```

When that is performed initially, it performs the segue and somewhere in that segue it is crashing.I have a version of the app in the App Store and it works fine. It just start about 10 minutes ago and it had been working all day until I started a new project and just applied all of the same provisioning stuff to it so I could use the push notifications.

I cannot use the same provisioning stuff from another app or something. I even replaced another project with the same stuff I have in the current one (the project I have on the app store) nothing is work!

**Edit**
This comes up when I step out

```
0x197301210:  b.ne   0x19730121c               ; pthread_kill + 100
0x197301214:  movz   w0, #45
0x197301218:  b      0x197301238               ; pthread_kill + 128
0x19730121c:  ldr    w0, [sp, #12]
0x197301220:  mov    x1, x19
0x197301224:  bl     0x197303c60               ; symbol stub for: vm_page_mask
---- >0x197301228:  cmn    w0, #1
0x19730122c:  b.ne   0x197301238               ; pthread_kill + 128
0x197301230:  bl     0x197303bac               ; symbol stub for: mach_task_self_
```

Help? (I have been using Xcode for about 6 months now)

Comment: Way too vague. Come back when you've actually found where the crash is.

Comment: @matt I would make it more detailed if I did know where it crashed. It'll finish the viewDidLoad and the after that it never executes another method. I crash is unknown. If i knew what $in was I wouldn't be asking

Comment: But when you crash you stop in a call stack. You have a backtrace. You should know exactly where you are.

Comment: `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));` this is where it ends @matt

Comment: Try to set a exceptional break point. And the comparison is not right. You should do something like `[_theUser[@"Completed"] boolValue] == false`. Or, you can use `compare` method.

Comment: No, that's your code. That just means we crashed somewhere in your application (UIApplicationMain _is_ the running application). Look at the call stack.

Comment: @LucasHuang how about `_theUser[@"Completed"] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` and I have break points going. it completes one method and then crashes

Comment: @matt I am looking at the call stack above the dotted line(I am assuming is where the issue is) 0__pthread_kill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing due to something in the code.  Set an exception breakpoint using the following steps:

See the following steps.

1. Look into [Navigator] and Click on [Show the Breakpoint Navigator].
2. See the bottom of Navigator [ + ] Sign. Click on it
3. Select [Add Exception Breakpoint].
4. Your Exception Breakpoint are activated from this things.

You may have breakpoints in your code, but putting and *exception breakpoint* is different.  It will let you see where you are doing something with a null variable that you shouldn't.

Comment: wow now this makes sense. I noticed there was some pquery running in the viewDidAppear and I had a segue occurring in the viewDidLoad. Thank you @wottle

Comment: No problem.  Exception breakpoints are important when debugging a problem that you can't seem to locate.